# SublimeText2: how to join lines using shortcuts

Tags: editor, sublimetext2

In Vim and Vintage mode for SublimeText2, I can use Shift+J to join selected lines together. How does this work in vanilla SublimeText2 without Vintage using a shortcut?

I've looked at key bindings and I can see that there is a mapping for `join_lines` command:

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "join_lines" },
```

However, pressing the combination doesn't do anything, and menu item doesn't show the shortcut. What is the right way to map this shortcut and is there another shortcut that I might have missed?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I am trying to do, I am trying to get something like this:

```
if (condition) {
    return;
}
```

to be joined like this:

```
if (condition) { return; }
```

(with or without spaces around `return;`.)

**EDIT2**

Not sure if this matters, but this is SublimeText2 on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on a line, in standard mode, hit ctrl-j (cmd-j os OSX) to join the line below to the current line.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Also, please see my updated question for the effect I'm looking for. I want to join multiple lines (three most of the time) at once.

Comment: to join three lines at once, i'd do, ctrl-l (select a line) three times, then hit ctrl-j (join line)

Comment: Actually, you only need to press CTRL+L once. The first time you press it, it will select the current line, and move the cursor to the next line. Since CTRL+J will merge the line where the cursor is located, any selected lines, plus the next line, it merges all three lines. My problem was that CTRL+J mapping wasn't working (see my own answer).

Comment: Since I think the key binding not working properly is just a bug, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Actually, just go anywhere on the first line, hit ctrl-j twice. The proceeding two lines will be joined by a space to the current line. If this isn't working for you, it's a bug. I just test it in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here, but it's just a workaround. Not sure if it's the correct way to do it.

I've copied the binding in the question to the user bindings file, and it works.